# Setting timeout for Jodd HTTP client?

Tags: jodd

I am using [Jodd HTTP](http://jodd.org/doc/http.html) client for testing some REST APIs. Everything works fine (great, actually:) except I am not sure how to set the socket time out value. So sometimes, when server is not up, I need to wait for long time (because of default systems timeout is big).

I am using http request like this:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.get("http://server").query("p1", "v1")....send();
```

I do not see any timeout related method in `HttpRequest` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here.

The first way is actually [described in the docs](http://jodd.org/doc/http.html#socket) :) Anyway, the idea is to tweak the `HttpConnection` like this:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get()...;
request.open();
SocketHttpConnection httpConnection = (SocketHttpConnection) request.httpConnection();
Socket socket = httpConnection.getSocket();
socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
...
HttpResponse response = request.send();
```

However, since this is something often required, we added in latest version (not yet released) the `timeout` method, so in the future you would be able to set it just with:

```
httpRequest.timeout(1000);
```

Hope this helps.